# GDAL clip raster by mask layer in Qgis 3.24.3-TIsler produces error "ERROR 1: Cutline transformation failed"

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

As the title implies. The shapefile seems to load just fine. Below is the screenshot showing an apparently well-formed cutline.[image]

Here is the log file:

```
QGIS version: 3.24.3-Tisler
QGIS code revision: cf22b74e01
Qt version: 5.12.8
Python version: 3.8.10
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020
PDAL version: 2.0.1 (git-version: Release)
Algorithm started at: 2022-05-16T21:29:51
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : '/home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : '/vsizip//home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/serbia.zip/serbia.shp|layername=serbia', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE|PREDICTOR=2|ZLEVEL=9', 'OUTPUT' : '/home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged_Clipped.tif', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_EXTENT' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTiff -cutline /vsizip//home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/serbia.zip/serbia.shp -cl serbia -crop_to_cutline -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 /home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged.tif /home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged_Clipped.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Cutline transformation failed
Copying color table from /home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged.tif to new file.
Creating output file that is 41777P x 60639L.
Processing /home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. 0) for image /home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged.tif.
Copying nodata values from source /home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged.tif to destination /home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged_Clipped.tif.
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.11 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/home/stefan/Downloads/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Serbia_Merged_Clipped.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' finished
```

For reference here is the shapefile: [serbia.zip](https://anonfiles.com/f2e6g3h5y3/serbia_zip)
This file was generated by loading the file [data.zip](https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:nw576pv0116/data.zip) into Python, merging all the municipalities so that only the border remains, converting the CRS to EPSG:32634, the converting the geometry to GeoJSON and then using:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt POLYGON -skipfailures serbia.shp serbia.geojson
```

converting it to `serbia.zip`

Comment: Please put all of the details in the Question, then write the title as summary; this way all the text to be searched is in one place.

Comment: @vince The only thing that is missing is the huge raster file. Should I upload thar?